# Postfix spam flood from my network

Tags: linux, centos, postfix, spam

I have some issues with my postfix server. Recently it started sending spams, but only in my local network, since open relay has been closed, only allow to my network. I've tried a lot of solutions and countless postfix settings, but they are still coming in. The server has spamassassin and has been recently cleaned for viruses.

```
disable_vrfy_command = yes
smtpd_delay_reject = yes
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
    permit_mynetworks
    permit_sasl_authenticated
    reject_unauth_destination
    warn_if_reject reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname
    warn_if_reject reject_unknown_helo_hostname
    warn_if_reject reject_unknown_client
    reject_non_fqdn_sender
    reject_non_fqdn_recipient
    reject_unknown_sender_domain
    reject_unknown_recipient_domain
    reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org
    reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net
    reject_rbl_client dnsbl.sorbs.net=127.0.0.2
    reject_rbl_client dnsbl.sorbs.net=127.0.0.3
    reject_rbl_client dnsbl.sorbs.net=127.0.0.4
    reject_rbl_client dnsbl.sorbs.net=127.0.0.5
    reject_rbl_client dnsbl.sorbs.net=127.0.0.7
    reject_rbl_client dnsbl.sorbs.net=127.0.0.9
    reject_rbl_client dnsbl.sorbs.net=127.0.0.11
    reject_rbl_client dnsbl.sorbs.net=127.0.0.12
    warn_if_reject reject_rhsbl_sender dsn.rfc-ignorant.org
    warn_if_reject reject_rhsbl_sender abuse.rfc-ignorant.org
    warn_if_reject reject_rhsbl_sender whois.rfc-ignorant.org
    warn_if_reject reject_rhsbl_sender bogusmx.rfc-ignorant.org
    warn_if_reject reject_rhsbl_sender postmaster.rfc-ignorant.org
    reject_unauth_pipelining
```

Can anyone give me a heads up ?
Thanks,
Alin

Comment: what in the mynetworks?

Comment: permit_mynetworks shouldn't be there ?

Comment: Should be and mynetworks should contain only 127.0.0.0/8

Comment: can you give me an example :D, something like permit 192.168.1.0/8

Comment: mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 192.168.1.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination

Comment: 192.168.1.0/8?! It's very very strange netmask. I think it should be 192.168.1.0/24

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check mail log (/var/log/maillog) and postfix queue `postfix -q` / `postcat -q [ID]` for sender addresses to know from where is spam originated.

Answer (score 0):

See if [Postfix Policyd v2 Cluebringer](http://www.policyd.org) has any use for you. It's a very capable Postfix plugin for rate-limiting SMTP on per-user/global basis.